# Get feature data from lat long input QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinates, feature-layer, spatial-query

In QGIS, I have a polygon dataset with feature data. I would like to extract data from this dataset using a latitude and longitude.

To be more clear, I have a list of 1000 coordinates. I would like QGIS to give me the feature data of the polygon based on my coordinate input. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to know what polygon(s) occur at 1,000 XY locations?  If so, can you edit your question to clarify that and also to mention how your "list of 1000 coordinates" is stored, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61301/how-to-join-attributes-by-location-in-qgis-1-8-0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, I will delete this post if I am mistaken.

Go to your Attribute Table, select *Show All Features* and then *Advanced Filter (Expression)*:

[image: Attribute Table]

In the expression box, enter:

```
xat(i) AND  yat(j)
```

and replace **i** and **j** with your coordinates. You should see the data associated with those coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Joseph, this will work if I have the exact coordinates. However, my input coordinates aren't exactly the same as the polygon's feature data content. I would like to pull the feature data of the polygon that my lat long falls inside of.(if there is any)